# Need to get the rest of an iterator in python

Tags: python, iterator

Say I have an iterator.
After iterating over a few items of the iterator, I will have to get rid of these first few items and return an iterator(preferably the same) with the rest of the items. How do I go about?
Also, Do iterators support remove or pop operations (like lists)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just use iter.next()

Example

```
iter = xrange(3).__iter__()

iter.next() # this pops 0

for i in iter:
  print i

1
2
```

You can pop off the front of an iterator with .next(). You cannot do any other fancy operations.

Comment: The "official", recommended way, in Python 2.6 and later, is next(iter), not iter.next() [that continues to work in 2.6, but not in 3.*]. With next(x) you can supply a default value as the second argument to avoid getting a StopIteration exception if the iterator is exhausted.

Answer (score 7):

The [`itertools.dropwhile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) function might be helpful, too:

```
dropwhile(lambda x: x<5, xrange(10))
```